# Accessing group-headings sub elements in data-bound GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing a windows 8 metro application with a data-bound gridview xaml control.

[image]

I've added a ring progress bar named progressRingGroup to header of the groups as seen below.

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="progressRingGroup" IsActive="True" Visibility="Visible" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,-7,0,0"/>
```

I want to programmatically access the ring-progress-bar from my code (so I can start/stop it) but as my grid-view is databound I don't know how to do so.

I've multiple groups in the gridview and need to access all of them separately.

Here's my gridview's groupstyle xaml definition;

```
<GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRingGroup" IsActive="True" Visibility="Visible" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,-7,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="6,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>                                        
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="75" ItemHeight="150" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to control the IsActive property of each progress ring, add a bool property to your group data model, and bind IsActive to that property. That way you can control each ProgressRing without having to programatically access all of them.

For example:

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="progressRingGroup" IsActive="{Binding GroupLoading}" Visibility="Visible" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,-7,0,0"/>
```

If you still want to access each programmatically, you could assign a `Loaded` event to the ProgressRing in the DataTemplate, and when the event fires, grab a reference to the ring (sender).